# How to store big int value in javascript with standard libraray

Tags: javascript

I am seeking a way to save large integer value in javascript. I know that there is some libraries out there but I want to know whether there is a standard way to do that without bring any dependency. Below is an example of my problem:

```
let a = 6703734870638684097
console.log(a)
```

and the output becomes to:

```
6703734870638684000
```

Comment: If there were a way to do it without a library, there would be no need for those libraries to exist, no?

Comment: @Pekka웃 [`npm left-pad`](http://www.haneycodes.net/npm-left-pad-have-we-forgotten-how-to-program/) -- just because there's a library for something, doesn't mean it can't be done without a library :P.

Comment: @Mike Ha! True, of course, especially these days. :) But in this case, literally every Google result for  `How to store big int value in javascript` says "you need a library."